# How to hide the second preview XML in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In android studio it shows two previews

[image]

How do I hide this second xml preview that shows the view type and `@+id/name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Design Surface" can either be switched by menu - or be toggled with button <kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]